# problem with permutation symbol

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Given $\varepsilon_{ijk}T_{ij} = 0$.

Prove that $T_{ij} = T_{ji}$

I can prove it by expanding summation. It is very cumbersome.
May be there is more compact solution?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to remember what happens to the sign of the permutation tensor when you permute some of the indices. Specifically, you need these two rules for any second order tensor *S*:

$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{ijk}S_{ij} &= \epsilon_{jik}S_{ji} \\
\epsilon_{ijk}S_{ij} &= -\epsilon_{jik}S_{ij} \\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\epsilon_{ijk}T_{ij} &= 0\quad\leftarrow Given \\
\epsilon_{ijk}T_{ij} &= -\epsilon_{ijk}T_{ij} \quad \leftarrow\text{Since }0=-0 \\
&= \epsilon_{jik}T_{ij} \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}T_{ji} \\
\epsilon_{ijk}(T_{ij}-T_{ji})&=0
\end{align}
$$

This must hold true for all second order tensors $T$, therefore $T_{ij} = T_{ji}$.